# Using insert value of a unit test as parameter for another

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I'm new to unit test and I was to test insert/update test of a repository.
I was wondering if it's possible (and how) to get the return value of a insert method (that insert into a sql table) and pass that value to another unit test as parameter.
For example I insert an object of type Animal and want to delete it

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Unit tests should be independant, should be runnable individually, or in any order. The insert test should insert an item and check that the row was correctly inserted. The delete test should delete an existing row and make sure it has been deleted. It's up to the test fixture to make sure that, before running the test, the row to insert doesn't exist yet, and the row to delete exists.

Comment: Test like this would not be actually a "unit" test — it would be more like an integration one. You can read [this article](http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters) to gain more understanding on unit testing, writing testable code and different types of tests (this article was written by me if you mind).